# In Java, why use a array over an arrayList

Tags: java

I've played around with arrays and arrayLists. Sorting is a breeze with arrayLists but I can not say the same with arrays. You have to make a for loop and filter the results and it's a pain. As far as I can see arrayList are just a better version of arrays. So why use arrays? Is there something they can do better.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/717399/2864464)

Comment: Oops didn't see that!

Answer (score 0):

Sorting with arrays and ArrayLists is equally easy: there are already implementations for sorting both of them:

- [Sorting ArrayLists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))
- [Sorting Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator))

The reasons for using one of the other are more of memory concerns, speed concerns or because your problems is better suited to be solved with one or the other.