# Add "Select item" on spinner where item comes from server

Tags: android

I want to implement one spinner where items comes from server and I want to add "Select item" on first row of spinner

This is spinner

```
    <Spinner
          android:background="@drawable/spinner_back"
          android:id="@+id/eduMinPart"
          android:layout_width="350dp"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:textSize="18dp"
          style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
          android:layout_below="@+id/EducationTV"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>
```

This is java code

```
  StringRequest strReqests = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,EDU_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    String[] arr = response.trim().split(",");
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
          (EditDetails7.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
           adapter.setDropDownViewResource
                  (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
           spinEducation.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(EditDetails7.this, error.toString(), 
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReqests);;
```

I used adapter.add("select Education") and prompt but both is not working.

Comment: Check if your **arr** is empty or not and I think you are missing a line **adapter.setDropDownViewResource(....);**

Comment: add 'Select item' at arr's 0th position. and then add your response to same array.

Comment: @Pallavi mam can you tell me how to add 'select Item' on 0th position of array

Answer (score 3):

This will work for you.

```
int arraySize = response.trim().split(",").length + 1;
String[] arr = new String[arraySize];
arr[0] = "select Item";
arr = response.trim().split(",");
```

Comment: I used this one  String s2 = "Select Item," + response.trim();
                          arr=s2.trim().split(",");                                                                                In your code arr 0th position takes item 'select Item' but when you override it arr=response.trim().split(","); arr 0th takes first item of response.

Comment: Why don't you try ArrayList instead of Array??

Answer (score 1):

```
String temp="select your what ever,"+response;
temp=response.trim().split(",");
```

Comment: I used this one  String s2 = "Select Item," + response.trim();
                          arr=s2.trim().split(",");                                                                                In your code arr 0th position takes item 'select Item' but when you override it arr=response.trim().split(","); arr 0th takes first item of response.

Comment: you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518195/how-can-i-add-new-item-to-the-string-array

Comment: Please put a little bit more explanation as to how the code above solves the issue

Comment: @VikasGodiyal please try above code let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Hey why don't you use the `ArrayList<String>` in Adapter instead of `Array`.

**Example:**

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(response.trim().split(",")));
arr.add(0, "Select Item")
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
(EditDetails7.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinEducation.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Note:**

The "Select Item" will be selectable from the Spinner. If you need to put it just as a header of the Spinner then you need to find some other solution.

Comment: If I use this code and spinner item is 'Select Item' then I will click on submit button so I need blank will go to server.

Comment: This issue is remain

Comment: Okay.. This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one/12221309#12221309

Comment: Before this implementation I used spinner.setPrompt("Select your favorite Planet!"); but it was not working on my spinner

Comment: I have one more idea to avoid this issue but I don't know my idea is good or not but it's working for me.                                                                                        
         String s6 = (spinner.equalsIgnoreCase("Select Item") ? "" 
         : spinner);                                                                                                                         I used this code when I send data to server