# add item in array list of android

Tags: android, arraylist, element

I want to add value getting from text view of android to an existing array list.e.g. my current array list contain values Cricket,Football and  by text view I want to add hockey in array list at last position ..then my array list become Cricket ,football,hockey. My array list of cricket and football is coming from previous activity.
But now it add only cricket and football but does not add hockey
How can I do it?

```
 resultArrGame+=resultArrGame.add(txtGame.getText().toString());
```

Comment: read arraylist documentation before asking

Comment: You should select one of the answers below as correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add new elements to an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843366/how-to-add-new-elements-to-an-array)

Comment: I would suggest you to read about Arraylist and clear your fundamentals of Java programming! Book can be helpful to you.

Answer (score 26):

This will definitely work for you...

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add(textview.getText().toString());
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to assign the result of the add operation to resultArrGame, and add can either return true or false, depending on if the operation was successful or not. What you want is probably just:

```
resultArrGame.add(txt.Game.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this add string to list on a button click

```
final String a[]={"hello","world"};
final ArrayAdapter<String> at=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,a);
final ListView sp=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
sp.setAdapter(at);
final EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int k=sp.getCount();
                String a1[]=new String[k+1];
                for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
                    a1[i]=sp.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                a1[k]=et.getText().toString();
                ArrayAdapter<String> ats=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,a1);
                sp.setAdapter(ats);
            }
        });
```

So on a button click it will get string from edittext and store in listitem.
you can change this to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
item=sp.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
list.add(item);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged () ;
```

[look up ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

Comment: please explain to make user understand better..