# How do I add another element?

Tags: java, android

I have this code in `ADT` Android

`private Titular [] datos = new Titular[] {};`

How do I add another element from `TextEdit` ?

Comment: Waaaay, too brief, add more detail than this.

Comment: You are going to get many downvotes. please edit your question and be more clear

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can't change the size of an Array after it has been instantiated.
You will have to collect your data in another collection type. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843366/how-to-add-new-elements-to-an-array) for example.

Answer (score 0):

use java.util.arraylist instead of using object array too brief