# I have seen the following code , where i want to add the results one by one into an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int limit = 100;
    System.out.println("Prime numbers between 1 and " + limit);
    for(int i=1; i < 100; i++){
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for(int j=2; j < i ; j++){

            if(i % j == 0){
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }}
        // print the number 
        if(isPrime)
            System.out.print(i + " ");
    }}}
```

I want to compare the each element in the result .So i want to add this result into an array. How can i add the result of this program into a array?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843366/how-to-add-new-elements-to-an-array

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add new elements to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843366/how-to-add-new-elements-to-an-array)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ArrayList to store all the prime numbers you found.

```
List primeNumbers = new ArrayList();
```

then add the number into list using 'add' method of the list.

```
if(isPrime){
  primeNumbers.add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda in java8.
for example

```
List<Integer> primes = IntStream.rangeClosed(2, 100)
            .filter(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(2, (int) Math.sqrt(i)).allMatch(j -> i % j != 0))
            .boxed().collect(toList());

    System.out.println(primes);
```