# change type of object into type I created in java

Tags: java

I'm managing a grocery list in a main class called `shoppingList`, and I created a new class named Product to handle the String (I get a string full of data on the product and in the class Product I use the `.split(";")` and arrays to arrange the data as needed.

On the main class - `shoppingList` - there is a method called `addProduct` that I need to execute, and this method get a `String`. How do I change this `String` to be type `Product` so I can add this product into an array of products (`products[currentNumOfProducts-1] = productLine`)?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class Product {
    private String type;
    private double price;
    private int id;
    private String manifactor;
    private ExtraData extraData;

    public Product(String item) {
        String[] parts = item.split(",");
        type = parts[0];
        type = parts[1];
        switch (type) {
            case "ElectricProduct":
                extraData = new ElctricExtraData(item);
                break;
            case "Book":
                extraData = new BookExtraData(item);
                break;
        ...
```

This is the class Product -and the method on Shopping list:

```
public void addProduct (String productLine){
                if (curNumOfProducts < products.length) {
                    products[curNumOfProducts - 1] = productLine;
                    curNumOfProducts++;
                }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add new elements to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843366/how-to-add-new-elements-to-an-array)

Comment: You'll have to show us the relevant code before we can give any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: public class Product {
 private String type;
 private double price;
 private int id;
 private String manifactor;
 private ExtraData extraData;
 
 public Product(String item) {
  String[] parts = item.split(",");
  type = parts[0];
  type = parts[1];
  
  switch (type) {
  case "ElectricProduct":
   extraData = new ElctricExtraData(item);
  break;
  case "Book":
   extraData = new BookExtraData(item); 
  break;

Comment: This is the class Product - and the method on Shopping list: 
public void addProduct (String productLine) {
  if (curNumOfProducts < products.length) {
   
   **products[curNumOfProducts-1] = productLine;**
   
   curNumOfProducts++;
  }

Comment: Post the code in the question. Code in comments is not readable at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have a string which represents a product info:

```
String productInfo = "product;info;here";
```

You can convert it into `Product` by passing it to the `Product` constructor:

```
Product product = new Product(productInfo);
```

so the original line

```
 products[curNumOfProducts - 1] = productLine;
```

becomes

```
 products[curNumOfProducts - 1] = new Product(productLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

... by going to the file "ShoppingList.java" and editing that source code to read `public void addProduct(Product product) {` instead.

If you cannot change that file, then what you're trying to do is not possible; that's just not how java works.