# How to add JTextField Value to String array using a button

Tags: java, arrays, button

I need to add the text that is typed into a `JTextField` to a string array `String[]` by using a `JButton`. For example, if I type into a `JTextField`, I would click a `JButton` which would add that text into a `String[]`. I can't use an `ArrayList` for this, I must use a `String stringa[]`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
      if(g.getSource() == jbutton) { 
            stringa.add(jtextfield.getText());            
}
```

It's very important to note I can't use an `ArrayList` but I don't know how to add to a `String[]`this way. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can not add an element to an array. Arrays have constant length in Java. you need to create a new array with `length + 1` from the old one and assign the last value.

Comment: Look here: [How to add new elements to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2843366/9662601) (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

What about doing something like this?

```
List<String> elems = new ArrayList<>();

elems.add(input.getText());

String[] out = new String[elems.size()];

out = elems.toArray(out);
```

This way you can add items to a list and then handle it as an array

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray-T:A-