# How to add an element to an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this method

```
public void addAttraction(Attraction c) {

}
```

which needs to add a element (an attraction in this case, c) to an array named Attraction[]. I tried using an ArrayList, and manually entering it using index. But niether seem to work.

This is what I tried:

```
public void addAttraction(Attraction c) {
    c = new Attraction();
}
```

It needs to give a value of 2 (when the method is used), but I get a 0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add new elements to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843366/how-to-add-new-elements-to-an-array)

Comment: That is a little bit unspecific. We need to see more to help you.

Comment: Here is a useful link to add an element to array:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-an-element-to-an-array-in-java/