# Can I add an element to an empty String vector in java?

Tags: java, string, vector

I'm working on a program that reverses a string by words and I have 2 vectors, `words`(the words but reversed, which is initiated with the words) and `words2`(the words, it's not initiated and I want to add the words). Is there any function that can add a String into a String[]?

Comment: It seems like a dynamic data type like ArrayList is more suitable here, but if you really want to have arrays, maybe the ArraysUtils library is useful https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#add-T:A-T-

Comment: `String[]` isn't a string vector, but a string array which has fixed length, it would be better to show your code; because in that case both would have same size so you stick to arrays for that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primitive array has a fixed size once you instantiate it. Unless you have a very specific need to use a primitive array, you can use an `ArrayList` and just add and remove elements from it.

```
List<String> yourList = new ArrayList<>();
yourList.add("foo");
System.out.println(yourList.get(0));
```

This will add the string `foo` at the end. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Well I can't do `ArrayList<String> words = text1.split("\\s");`  so I need to use a vector

Comment: Nobody can, because `String::split` produces a primitive array. You need to do `ArrayList<String> words = Arrays.asList(text1.split("\\s"))` Still no reason to use a primitive array.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2843371/4926545).

In short, an array in Java cannot be resized. If you want to add an element, you would need to create a new bigger array and copy the contents from the array you have, or use a different container more suitable to your needs.