# Why is Collections.addAll supposed to be faster than c.addAll

Tags: java, collections, performance

The [Java API docs say](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll(java.util.Collection,%20T...)) the following about `Collections.addAll`

> The behavior of this convenience method is identical to that of c.addAll(Arrays.asList(elements)), but this method is likely to run significantly faster under most implementations.

So if I understand correctly, a) is slower than b):

a)

```
Collection<Integer> col = new ArrayList<Integer>();
col.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

b)

```
Collection<Integer> col = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// Collections.addAll(col, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)); <-- won't compile
Collections.addAll(col, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Can anyone explain to me, why that is?

edited:
corrected code example. thx to [polygenelubricants](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276101/polygenelubricants)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at the two of them:

> ```
> // a)
> col.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
> ```

Here's what happens:

1. varags + autoboxing creates `Integer[]`
2. `Arrays.asList` creates a `List<Integer>` backed by the array
3. `addAll` iterates over a `Collection<Integer>` using `Iterator<Integer>`

> ```
> // b)
> Collections.addAll(col, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
> ```

Here's what happens:

1. varargs + autoboxing creates `Integer[]`
2. `addAll` iterates over an array (instead of an `Iterable<Integer>`)

We can see now that `b)` may be faster because:

- `Arrays.asList` call is skipped, i.e. no intermediary `List` is created.
- Since the elements are given in an array (thanks to varargs mechanism), iterating over them may be faster than using [`Iterator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

That said, unless profiling shows otherwise, the difference isn't likely to be "significant". Do not optimize prematurely. While Java Collection Framework classes may be slower than arrays, they perform more than adequately for most applications.

#### API links

- [`Collections.addAll(Collection<? super T> c, T... elements)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection,%20T...%29) - varargs i.e. array-based
- [`Collection.addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) - `Collection`-based

#### See also

- [Java Language Guide/Autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)
- [Java Language Guide/Varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)
- *Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 25: Prefer lists to arrays*

#### Related questions

- [Array or List in Java. Which is faster ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716597/array-or-list-in-java-which-is-faster)

---

#### Summary

- If you're adding elements from an array, you can use `Collections.addAll(col, arr)`

  - Remember that varargs are also done using arrays
- If you're adding elements from a `Collection`, use `col.addAll(otherCol)`

  - Do *NOT* e.g. `Collections.addAll(col, otherCol.toArray())`

    - Such roundabout way is likely to be slower!
- It's not that one is supremely faster than the other

  - It's about skipping unnecessary steps given the current situation

Comment: My personal opinion is that the documentation is slightly confusing in that regard, as I fail to see how the implementation of that method has anything to do with it. It is the usage of the method, and the fact that you don't have to package up the data in an extra step that makes it faster. Or is there something else about the method that makes it faster as well?

Comment: Sadly, the code in (b) only works with literal integers; autoboxing won't convert an array.  For example, "int[] arr = {...create array...}; Collections.addAll(col, arr);" will fail because Integer and 'int' aren't in an inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: What about when using `Collections.addAll()` to add the contents of an array to a `HashSet`?  As compared to `for (Foo f : fooArray) { set.add(f); }`?

Answer (score 3):

The only reason it might be faster is that it avoids the call to Arrays.asList which should be relatively cheap since it just wraps the array. Some Collection implementations, for example LinkedList convert the passed collection back to an array before adding the elements, causing additional overhead.

On the other hand, ArrayList.addAll allocates the needed space once before adding any elements and so should be much faster when Collections.addAll requires multiple resizing of the backing array.

In summary, Collections.addAll could be faster when repeatedly adding only a few elements to a collection, but I doubt that this case would ever be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: There's also the iteration factor, i.e. iterating over an array `T[]` (which is what varargs is in Java) vs iterating over a `Collection<E>`, i.e. an `Iterable<E>` through its `Iterator<E>`.

Comment: for the particular case of an `ArrayList`, you can always `al.ensureCapacity(al.size() + array.length)` first.  Though yes, probably not going to be enough of a bottleneck that one would want to make a field an `ArrayList` instead of a `List`.

Comment: @Carl: _Effective Java 2nd Edition, Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces_. You should generally not have a field declared as an `ArrayList` instead of a `List`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the specific `addAll` implementation quirks of `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: my comment says that already, if perhaps not as specifically.  Legitmate performance concerns can be a reason to violate that particular piece of EJ advice - again, I doubt that's the case here.

Answer (score 1):

(Let's build on SE Platform 6)

It all depends on actual collection implementation. In your example we have

`Collection<Integer> col = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

and `addAll` method in `ArrayList` is overriden. No iterations whatsoever.
Here's the source:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
Object[] a = c.toArray();
    int numNew = a.length;
ensureCapacity(size + numNew);  // Increments modCount
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, size, numNew);
    size += numNew;
return numNew != 0;
}
```

As you might notice `c.toArray()` also depends on actual implementation. Again, in your case `Arrays.asList()` results in `ArrayList` which one's version of `toArray()` method looks like this:

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
}
```

This static method is based on `System.arraycopy`

So actually what we deal here with is two calls of `System.arraycopy` which is not that bad actually because it's a native method, specifically optimized for current operation system.

So, to sum it all up in Mr. polygenelubricants' style:

1. varags + autoboxing creates `Integer[]`
2. `Arrays.asList` creates an `ArrayList<Integer>`
3. `ArrayList.addAll` calls `System.arraycopy(size)`x2, size = 5

In your case of 5 objects in the array `Collections.addAll` is of cource faster. BUT irrelevant with such a small array size. On the other hand if it was, say, 100k elements in an array then `col.addAll(Arrays.asList(...))` is much more efficient 'cause with native method it is a single memcpy/memmove we dealing with as opposed to 100k iterations/copy operations.

And again, it all depends on collection's implementation. `LinkedList` for example will iterate over it as was expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the (approximate) associated time complexity cost functions for each of the steps mentioned by @polygenelubricants:

a) 3 iterations over arguments list ~= C(3N)

b) 2 iterations over arguments list ~= C(2N)

Clearly they are both O(N) but approach b) saves ~N comparisons over approach a). Hopefully this is helpful to anyone who was interested in a quantitative explanation.