# DDMS allocation tracker filled with "SimpleListIterator"

Tags: java, android, foreach, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I'm trying to crack down on a memory leak which is causing the heap to run out of memory and the GC to get invoked. A lot.

Logcat is filled with messages like this:

> 11-27 20:54:39.052: DEBUG/dalvikvm(32167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 405K,
>   5% free 11046K/11591K, paused 2ms+3ms

I used the DDMS Allocation tracker to see if there was anything in particular getting allocated more than usual, and the instant that I clicked the 'Get Allocations' button in Eclipse, the list was filled with *java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator*
They get allocated during the main game loop, so there are lots, and I believe this is what is eating the heap memory.(there are approx. 509 allocations of SimpleListIterator)

However,
DDMS is telling me that they are being allocated wherever there is a for-each loop, which I think is strange. o_O

Normally I would use a regular for loop, but [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#foreach) recommends using the for-each loop instead since it's faster, but it mentions nothing about its memory usage

Could all these allocations be the result of using the for-each loop instead of the regular for loop? (It'll take a while to go in and change every single for-each loop in my app, so I'd rather ask first)
If they are, then is this normal? Is it a programming error on my part?

**UPDATE**
I changed the for-each loops to regular for loops and the completely solved the problem. I still think its dumb though that I had to do that

Comment: Did you read the relevant topics about this issue here on SO?

Comment: which 'relevant topics'?

Comment: See "answer" (quotes) below...

Comment: Perhaps you should post your code and error lines.

Answer (score 0):

**Big Fat Disclaimer**: this is not really an answer (maybe). I don't know about this topic beyond what I've read. I'd rather post this as a comment, but the size limitation and formatting features makes an answer a better, constructive, alternative. I don't understand this subject enough to answer, and I'm helping the research only.

On the [Android dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#foreach):

> **With an ArrayList, a hand-written counted loop is about 3x faster** (with or without JIT), but for other collections the enhanced for loop syntax will be exactly equivalent to explicit iterator usage.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716597/array-or-list-in-java-which-is-faster/717205#717205), a user benchmarked a for-each loop:

> n.b. I did notice that using for String s: stringsList was about 50% slower than using an old-style for-loop to access the list. Go figure... Here's the two functions I timed; the array and list were filled with 5000 random (different) strings.

Below, another user warns about benchmarks. Personally, I doubt the use of a for loop would create such a problem on your code, as I've been wary of micro-benchmarking in Java. For what I've seen, it all boils down to microseconds of the Iterator object running. I believe you're doing something wrong, as just because you removed the enhanced for and it performed better doesn't imply that the enhanced for itself is slow or bad.

[On another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839494/enhanced-for-loop-performance-worse-than-traditional-indexed-lookup):

> **TL;DR**: enhanced loops are indeed slower than a traditional index-based loop over an arraylist; but for most applications the difference should be negligible.

[See a doc](http://today.java.net/article/2006/11/03/nuances-java-50-each-loop) about the enhanced for loop. You shouldn't be changing the list at will while in the loop. If that relates to your problem, I don't know. Perhaps maybe if I see the code and log lines.

So, I'd guess you're doing something wrong on your code. :-) But it would be better to wait until experienced people come up here.