# Difference between List and Array

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Primitive Array vs ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869212/primitive-array-vs-arraylist)

What is the difference between List and Array in java? or the difference between Array and Vector!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869212/primitive-array-vs-arraylist - arrays are primitives, `List` is an interface which defines a set of operations on sequential containers, and `Vector implements List`. Unless you meant `ArrayList`, and not `Array`.

Comment: you should read their documentation before posting a question: interface [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), class [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and class [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In general (and in Java) an array is a data structure generally consisting of sequential memory storing a collection of objects.

`List` is an [interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29) in Java, which means that it may have multiple implementations. One of these implementations is `ArrayList`, which is a class that implements the behavior of the `List` interface using arrays as the data structure.

There are a number of other classes that implement the `List` interface. One easy way to take a look at them is by viewing the Javadoc for `List`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

On that page, you'll see "all known implementing classes," which are all of the kinds of lists in Java.