# Code reading and memory locations

Tags: java, arrays, location

```
short[] foo = new short[45];
```

assuming that a short occupies 2 bytes and that the array starts at address 5342, which locations does foo[24] occupy? 
If possible please show how you figure it out and individually list ALL the addresses occupied.

This is not homework, i'm asking this because i really don't understand how to do this and it would be a great if i can see the solution so i can study

also, is this how i should approach this question, 5342+2*24

Comment: Can you explain what you would hope to achieve with that information? Bear in mind that arrays are objects - so there's also the type information, a monitor for synchronization, and the length...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Java store primitive types in RAM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832717/how-does-java-store-primitive-types-in-ram)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after working with a friend i was able to figure out how what to do.

the starting address: 5342
short occupied 2 bytes

==> starting address = b+i*s

b, base address of array: 5342

i, address of element: 24

s, size in bytes: 2

==>starting address: 5342 + (24)*2 = 5390

location foo[24] occupied (ALL address occupied) 5390 (1 byte) to 5391 (1 byte) ==> 2 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the reference address: [Is there a way to get a reference address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820164/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-reference-address)

Your approach of  5342+2*24 does't sound promising to me as Java array is sequential in virtual memory not necessarily in physical memory [Java Array Memory Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799928/is-array-in-java-virtually-sequential-memory-data-structure-or-physically-seque)