# What is the difference between byte[] and List<Byte> in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, byte

Both can be used to create an list of bytes. But what is the difference between them?

```
byte[] buffer;
List<Byte> buffer;
```

Comment: A `List<Byte>` is not an array of bytes.

Comment: A `List<Byte>` is a `List` not an array. `byte` is a primitive type, `Byte` is its wrapper class, like `int` and `Integer`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Both can be used to create an array of bytes

No, the first one creates an array of bytes. The second one defines a **list** of bytes, which may or may not be backed by an array depending on which `List` implementation you use.

An array is fixed-size and pre-allocated; if you need to grow the array, you need to create a *new*, larger array, copy the contents over, and then add the new contents.

Lists, on the other hand, are generally dynamic, growing as you add things to them, shrinking as you remove things from them, etc. One list implementation, `ArrayList`, does this by maintaining a backing array, usually with some slack in it, and then doing the reallocation-and-copy as necessary when you add to it.

Also note that `List` can't actually contain primitive `byte` values; instead, it'll contain `Byte` objects (via a process called autoboxing).

Comment: is there anyway to convert a List<Byte> object into a byte[] array?

Comment: @Tardo Sure. 1) create a `byte[]` with the size of the list; 2) traverse the list; 3) for each `Byte` in the list, insert its primitive value into the array.

Comment: @Tardo: Well, there's that tempting [`List#toArray(T[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) method on the `List` interface. I've never used it to auto-unbox `List<Byte>` to `byte[]`, don't know whether that would be automatic.

Comment: @Tardo: Just tried it, and no, you can't use `List#toArray(T[] a)` unless I was doing it wrong (you can get `Byte[]`, but not `byte[]`). So as afsantos said, you'd have to do it with a loop.

Answer (score 4):

- The `byte[]` array has a fixed size, while the list doesn't.
- The `byte[]` array contains **primitive** `byte` values, while the list contains **boxed** ones, therefore the list will need more memory

More info:

- [What's the difference between List and array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487104/difference-between-list-and-array)

Answer (score 2):

`byte[] buffer` is a premitive array of premetive `byte` without any methods that can be made either on the `Byte` and either in the `[]` 
`List<Byte> buffer` is List object of Byte object which also have methods on it which defined in `Byte`