# Adding a new row to String array

Tags: java

Suppose I have a two dimensional array, e.g. `String array[][] = {{"",""},{"",""}}` and this array prints out each row in a new line.

Now, my question is, if a user wants to add to this array with a new set of rows via a `Scanner` input how do I go about doing that?

For example, suppose I have a list of inventory and I just noticed a new shipment arrived. How do I add this new inventory to the existing inventory.

> What I was thinking was, if my array isn't large enough, then I would have to make a new, bigger array and copy the original data there. From this point, I can add the new data. So I was thinking a couple of for loops should suffice. But I don't know how to apply it here?

Comment: Java arrays aren't dynamically sized... so use a `List`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can you elaborate please?

Comment: You can't add to an array, their size is fixed. If you want the number of things in the collection to change you need to use a different structure like an implementation of List.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487104/difference-between-list-and-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can increase the size of an array by calling `Arrays.copyOf` method and then reassigning it to initial object. But anyhow if you don't want to go through copying again and again `ArrayList` is a better choice since it internally uses `Arrays.copyOf` to increase the size of Array as it internally does it when you call add(E e) as:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

`ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1)` checks for the max of Default capacity allocated i.e. 10 to size+1 as:

```
private void ensureCapacityInternal(int minCapacity) {
    if (elementData == DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA) {
        minCapacity = Math.max(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, minCapacity);
    }
    ensureExplicitCapacity(minCapacity);
}
```

If the capacity exceeds `ensureExplicitCapacity(minCapacity);` is called which increases the capacity of `transient Object[]` by calling `grow()` which internally does `Arrays.copyOf`.
Hope this explanation helps.

For your problem you can perform it as:

```
String array[][] = { { "hello", "how" }, { "are", "you" } };
Scanner scan = null;
String str = null;
int len = array.length;
int i = 0;
while (i != 6) { // provide the loop as you require
    scan = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    str = scan.next();
    try {
        array[len][1] = str; // will try to add to second position. If array is out of index an exception will be thrown
        len++; // won't increase if exception is thrown 
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        array = Arrays.copyOf(array, len + 1); // copying the array
        array[len] = new String[2]; // creating and assigning string array to new row else it will be null
        array[len][0] = str; // adding new string to new array position
    }
    i++;
}
scan.close();

for (String[] strings : array) {
    for (String string : strings) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the arrays.copyof? What I was thinking was, if my array isn't large enough, then I would have to make a new, bigger array and copy the original data there. From this point, I can add the new data. So I was thinking a couple of for loops should suffice. But I don't know how to apply it here?

Comment: @Robben edited the answer with solution of the scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java arrays are not dynamically sized data structures, I suggest you use a `Collection` (like `List`) which is (an interface type representing a dynamically sized data structure). Something like,

```
List<List<String>> al = new ArrayList<>();
al.add(Arrays.asList("1", "2"));
al.add(Arrays.asList("3", "4"));
String str = "5, 6"; // <-- let's assume the user wants to add a 5 and 6
al.add(Arrays.asList(str.split(",\\s*")));
System.out.println(al);
```

Output is

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

**Note** that unlike arrays, `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` both override `toString()`.

Comment: Hm, what I was thinking was, if my array isn't large enough, then I would have to make a new, bigger array and copy the original data there. From this point, I can add the new data. So I was thinking a couple of for loops should suffice. But I don't know how to apply it here?

Comment: Use the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28336676/2970947) provided by @sprinter below if you want an implementation of that sort... note that your approach will involve modifying the array reference on every addition.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are fixed size. You cannot change the size unless you create a new array each time.

A proper way will be using `ArrayList`.

```
List<String> shipments = new ArrayList<String>();
shipments.add("newShipments");
```

I see that you have more that one attribute in your records. You can create a Shipment class. (If you have more than one string or variable needed in your record, you can create an arraylist of objects as follows:)

**Example:**

```
class Shipment
{
    //Place your attributes here..
    String name;
    String id;

    //Constructors and methods not shown
}

List<Shipment> records = new ArrayList<Shipment>();
records.add(new Shipment("Dresses", "A-123"));

//Having an arraylist of objects allows you to hold more than 1 variable.
//Now each `records` can hold 2 String variables `name` and `id`.
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expand an array in place - it needs to be copied to a new array. Fortunately there is a method to make this easy for you: `Arrays.copyOf`.

So:

```
String[] names = {"Bill", "Bob"};
names = Arrays.copyOf(names, names.length + 1);
names[names.length - 1] = "Mary";
```

Answer (score 0):

> Case 1:Using **Array**

Suppose

```
String array[][] = {{"oldinventory1","oldinventory2"},{"oldinventory3","oldinventory4"}};
```

and you want new inventory to be inserted at a[2](https://ideone.com/R2VsLS) you do

```
array[2][2]="newinventory1";
```

It wiil give an array index out of bound as there is no  a[2](https://ideone.com/R2VsLS) index in array because array row and col are fixed in the first.

#### ARRAY DEMO

> Case 2:Using **List**

You can remove arraysize problem by using List.And there is also one more advantage by declaring List inside List as given in example by @Elliott Frisch

```
         List<List<String>> al = new ArrayList<>();
         al.add(Arrays.asList("oldinventory1", "oldinventory2"));
         al.add(Arrays.asList("oldinventory3", "oldinventory4"));
         String str = "newinventory5, newinventory6,, newinventory6";
```

i.e  not only we can increase the row dynamically but also we can add new column.So if inventory increase at any time you say from 3 to 5 or to 1 you can handle easily .


#### LIST DEMO

Comment: Hm, what I was thinking was, if my array isn't large enough, then I would have to make a new, bigger array and copy the original data there. From this point, I can add the new data. So I was thinking a couple of for loops should suffice. But I don't know how to apply it here?

Comment: @Robben is the new array have fixed inputs means the shipment have any limit or not.

Comment: We can place a limit to 10 columns where as the rows have no limit. So `array[][10]`.

Comment: @Robben check https://ideone.com/xYLTXx I have fixed the size to a[][2] you can change it by setting maxcol

Answer (score 0):

The size of arrays are fixed, so you need to copy the array to a bigger one. You can use `Arrays.copyOf()` to make the copy.

This is an example of use of the copyOf method with a multidimensional array.

```
    String[][] array = {{"A", "B"},{"C", "D"}};
    String[] newValuesArray = {"E", "F"};
    array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + 1);
    array[array.length - 1] = newValuesArray;
```