# In case of an arraylist in Java. What will the maximum capacity of the list

Tags: java

Now as per SCJP the arraylist max. size should be depending on the size of available memory, but list.getSize() returns an Integer. So is it safe to assume that `INTEGER.MAXSIZE` is the max. capacity of array . i.e int Max allowed value

Answer (score 5):

Well, since `ArrayList` is backed by an array, its max capacity can't be higher than the max length of an array, which is bound by `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (since the index of an array is always an `int`).

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size the maximum size of a Java array depends on the VM, and is in some cases less than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @sdgfsdh Either I misread your comment or you edited it. I thought you were referring to the max size of an ArrayList, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

There is another question with an answer matching your question and also an simple example to test: [Do Java arrays have a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size).

There are two limits:

1.- The available memory

2.- The max size of an Integer

But im pretty sure you hit the first before the second limit.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think I read about a proposal for `long` indexed arrays, so some people do seem to have enough memory to want such a thing. But, yeah, for most people, the memory limit must be the first wall they run into.

Answer (score 0):

From different sources:

> List is an interface in Java, which means that it may have multiple implementations. One of these implementations is ArrayList, which is a class that implements the behavior of the List interface using arrays as the data structure.

[Arrays vs Arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487104/difference-between-list-and-array)

And since Arraylist is based on arrays, you max size should be:

> Java arrays are accessed via 32-bit ints, resulting in a maximum theoretical array size of 2147483647 elements.

[Max array size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382531/why-i-cant-create-an-array-with-large-size)

Well, If your elements has a memory footprint big enough you could either deplete your VM's heap size or your machines memory before reaching that number, though.

Answer (score 0):

> ArrayList max capasity is Integer.MAX_VALUE -8 and ArrayList can throw OutOfMemoryError

```
private static int hugeCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    if (minCapacity < 0) // overflow
        throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    return (minCapacity > MAX_ARRAY_SIZE) ?
        Integer.MAX_VALUE :
        MAX_ARRAY_SIZE;
}
 /**
 * The maximum size of array to allocate.
 * Some VMs reserve some header words in an array.
 * Attempts to allocate larger arrays may result in
 * OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
 */
private static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;
```

> LinkedList is not limited in capacity but it can return not valid size

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    linkLast(e);
    return true;
}
void linkLast(E e) {
    final Node<E> l = last;
    final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(l, e, null);
    last = newNode;
    if (l == null)
        first = newNode;
    else
        l.next = newNode;
    size++;
    modCount++;
}
```