# misunderstanding the generic in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, generics

I am trying to understand generics in Java.

```
private List<Own> l = new ArrayList<Own>();
```

I have the following error :

```
no instance of Typed array variable T exist so that List<Own> conform to T[]
```

when I pass it in a method (readTypedArray) that expects T[].

```
private List<Own> list = new ArrayList<Own>();

private OwnParceable(Parcel in) {
    in.readTypedArray(list, CategoriesParceable.CREATOR);
}
```

Comment: `List` is not `[]`.

Answer (score 3):

The method `in.readTypedArray()` expects an array `T[]`, but you passed a `List<Own`  which is not an array.

`List` is not an `array` you can't use it where an array is expected, `List` is an interface which extends `Collection` while `array` is a data structure in Java, check **[Difference between List and Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487104/difference-between-list-and-array)** for further details.

You can either declare an `Own[]`instead of `List<Own>` or convert this list into an array before passing it to the method, check [Convert list to array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572795/convert-list-to-array-in-java):

```
in.readTypedArray(list.toArray(new Own[list.size()]), CategoriesParceable.CREATOR);
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with generics - `List`s and arrays are just two different things. If your method expects an array, you need to pass it an array, not a List:

```
Own[] arr = new Own[10]; // Or some size that makes sense...
in.readTypedArray(arr, CategoriesParceable.CREATOR);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to create an array filled with content of specified `List`. To achieve that you can call method `toArray()` of your list reference, for example:

```
Integer[] array = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
```