# Speeds of Accessing Arrays vs. ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Array or List in Java. Which is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716597/array-or-list-in-java-which-is-faster)

I started a project where I will be constantly accessing an Arraylist that will never be changed. Would it be faster to access an ArrayList or an Array and by how much?

Answer (score 3):

The difference will probably not be noticeable as the JVM will most likely optimise the call if you use it very often. And using `List` will give you a more robust and flexible code, so I would personally use `List`s.

There is only one way to know: test it (after having read this post about [how to test the performance of a Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)).

Answer (score 0):

if its constant, how about an Enum, you can add logic directly to the enum instances.