# How to map the database values to object array?

Tags: java, jdbc

```
public C[] getC() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException  {
   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
   String url = "jdbc:odbc:Mydb";
   String user = "user1";
   String password = "password";
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
   Statement smt= con.createStatement();
   String query = "Select ssn, cname from customer";
   ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery(query);
   C [] c = new C[getNumberOfCustomers()];
   while (rs.next()){
      String ssn = rs.getString("ssn");
      String customer_name = rs.getString("cname");
   }    
   return custarray;    
}
```

Here is the code of C:

```
public class C {

   private String name;
   private String SocialSecurityNumber;

   public C(String name, String SocialSecurityNumber) {
      this.name = name;
      this.SocialSecurityNumber = SocialSecurityNumber;
   }

   public String getName() { return name; }
   public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
   public String getSocialSecurityNumber() { return SocialSecurityNumber; }
   public void setSsn(String SocialSecurityNumber ) {
      this.SocialSecurityNumber = SocialSecurityNumber;
   }
}
```

Here I am having problem in passing ssn and customer_name to the `C[]` array

Comment: Please post the code of C

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: You forget to actually create C objects (bad name btw) and add them to the array. Is that your actual problem? Did that really need a question?

Answer (score 1):

```
C [] c = new C[getNumberOfCustomers()];
int i = 0;
while (rs.next()){
   c[i++] = new C( rs.getString( "cname" ), rs.getString( "ssn" ));
}
```

FYI: A `List<C>` [will be better than an array of `C`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716597/array-or-list-in-java-which-is-faster), the following code use a reusable list, `new` occurs only when `target == null` (first time use for example).

```
public List<C> getC( List<C> target ) throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException{
   if( target == null ) {
      target = new LinkedList<C>();
   }
   else {
      target.clear();
   }
   Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
   String url = "jdbc:odbc:Mydb";
   String user = "user1";
   String password = "password";
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
   Statement smt= con.createStatement();
   String query = "Select ssn, cname from customer";
   ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery(query);
   while( rs.next()){
      target.add( new C( rs.getString("cname"), rs.getString("ssn")));
   } 
   return target;
}
```

Comment: I am getting nullpointerexception for the above.Here is the code public class C {
 private String name; 
 private String SocialSecurityNumber;
 
 public C(String name, String SocialSecurityNumber) {
  this.name = name;
  this.SocialSecurityNumber = SocialSecurityNumber;
 }
 
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }
 
 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 
 public String getSocialSecurityNumber() {
  return SocialSecurityNumber;
 }
 public void setSsn(String SocialSecurityNumber) {
  this.SocialSecurityNumber = SocialSecurityNumber;
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
List<C> list = new ArrayList<C>();
while (rs.next()){
    String ssn = rs.getString("ssn");
    String customer_name = rs.getString("cname");
    C c = new C(ssn, customer_name);
    list.add(c);
}
C[] lc = new C[list.size()];
list.toArray(lc);
```

Comment: You are assuming the existence of a particular `C` constructor.  What makes you think it actually exists?