# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException object array

Tags: java, sql, arrays, object, exception

Hi I am trying to create a program that collects tasks from a database and displays them for editing. There is an issue that I am not sure how to resolve.

I want to load the several task objects with info from the database. The error only shows up when the program is actually ran.

This is the **error**:

```
Please enter a corresponding number: 2
This works? 1
5.6.25-log
This works? 2
This works? 3
This works? 4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at mytaskapp.DatabaseConnectTaskSelect.Connect(DatabaseConnectTaskSelect.java:65)
at mytaskapp.Display.TaskOutput(Display.java:175)
at mytaskapp.Display.StartScreen(Display.java:51)
at mytaskapp.MyTaskApp.main(MyTaskApp.java:16)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

My **code** is

```
public static void Connect()
{
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stu = null;
    ResultSet rsu = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tasks";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "cinder";        

    try {
        int index = 1;            
        TaskObject[] task = new TaskObject[index];
        System.out.println("This works? 1");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");

        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }

        System.out.println("This works? 2");
        pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT mainTaskString, timeCreated, dateCreated, timeDue, dateDue, "
                                 + "notes, project, catagory, taskLength, priority, remind1TimeDue, remind1DateDue, "
                                 + "remind2TimeDue, remind2DateDue FROM usertasks");

        rsu = pst.executeQuery();

        System.out.println("This works? 3");
        while (rsu.next()) {
            index = 1;
            //task[index] = new TaskObject(index);
            System.out.println("This works? 4");
            task[index].setTask(rsu.getString("mainTaskString"));
            System.out.println("This works? 4.1");
            task[index].setDateCreated(rsu.getString("timeCreated") + " " + rsu.getString("dateCreated"));
            System.out.println("This works? 4.2");
            task[index].setDateDue(rsu.getString("timeDue") + " " + rsu.getString("dateDue"));
            System.out.println("This works? 4.3");
            task[index].setNotes(rsu.getString("notes"));
            task[index].setProject(rsu.getString("project"));
            task[index].setCatagory(rsu.getString("catagory"));
            task[index].setTaskLength(rsu.getInt("taskLength"));
            task[index].setPriority(rsu.getInt("priority"));
            task[index].setRemind1DateDue(rsu.getString("remind1TimeDue") + " " + rsu.getString("remind1DateDue"));
            task[index].setRemind2DateDue(rsu.getString("remind2TimeDue") + " " + rsu.getString("remind2DateDue"));

            System.out.println("This works? 5");
            System.out.println("Your Task: " + task[index].getTask() + "\n" + " Date Created: " + task[index].getDateCreated() + " Date Due: " +  task[index].getDateDue() + 
                               " Your Notes: " +  task[index].getNotes() + "\n" + " Project: " + task[index].getProject() + " Catagory: " +  task[index].getCatagory() + " The minutes needed to complete: " +  task[index].getTaskLength() +
                               " Priority: " + task[index].getPriority() +  " Reminder 1: "  + 
                               task[index].getRemind1DateDue() +  " Reminder 2: "  +  task[index].getRemind2DateDue() + "\n");
            System.out.println("This works? 6");
            //index++;
        }
```

Comment: *index = 1. That is not causing the problem btw.

Comment: What about `index = ;`?

Comment: Indeed - please provide a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem. At the moment you're missing a crucial part (the value you're assigning to `index`) but you've got a lot of irrelevant JDBC code.

Comment: You are creating array TaskObject[] task of size 1. So when your query returns 1+ records, the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException is being thrown. You need to increase the array size or instead use an ArrayList.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "complete". I fixed the index part. it gives the same error.

Comment: create an object of TaskObject before storing it in array - task[index] = new TaskObject();

Comment: I add changed it but it just gives me the NullpointerException.              int index = 1;
            
            TaskObject[] task = new TaskObject[1000];
            System.out.println("This works? 1");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define size of Array `only once`. So make sure you define it proper otherwise it will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you try to put values more then specified in the size.

In your code you have specified size as `1`. So when you try to put more then 1 value in your `task` array, you will get this exception.

So make sure you specify enough size say 50.

But I would recommend to use `List` instead of `Array`, as it gives flexibility automatically increase size without specifying size. You can refer [`Array or List in Java`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716597/array-or-list-in-java-which-is-faster).

---

You can make following changes in your code

Declare `taskList` instead of task array.

```
List<TaskObject> taskList = new ArrayList<TaskObject>();
```

In `while` loop `create object` of TaskObject, `set values` into it and then `add` it to taskList.

```
TaskObject taskObject = null;
while (rsu.next()) {
    taskObject = new TaskObject();

    taskObject.setTask(rsu.getString("mainTaskString"));
    //set remaining value

    //Add taskObject in List
    taskList.add(taskObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int index = 1;            
    TaskObject[] task = new TaskObject[index];
```

This will create the array of the object of type TaskObject with the size 1. That means **it can have only task[0]**. If you give **task[1] it is array out of bound**.

So in the while loop it should be (according to your exp)

```
  index = 0;
        System.out.println("This works? 4");
        task[index].setTask(rsu.getString("mainTaskString"));
```

If your query is returning fixed number of rows then it is advisable to use array else use arraylist.