# Check how many rectangles cover a point

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a list of points `[[1,2], [2,3], [1,5]]` each point represents a rectangle with dimensions `[0,0], [x, 0], [0, y], [x,y]`.
Here for example for `[1,2], x =1 and y = 2` so rectangle dimentions are `[0,0], [1, 0], [0, 2], [1,y]`

Now I have another list of points  `[[1,1], [1,4]]`. Now my task is to check how many rectangles can cover these points.

```
For example: [[1,1], [1,4]

[1,1] is covered by [1,2], [2,3], [1,5] so 3.
[1,4] is covered by [1,5] only so 1.
```

Here is my program:

```java
public List<Integer> process(List<List<Integer>> inp1, List<List<Integer>> inp2) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (List<Integer> p1 : inp2) {
        int a = p1.get(0), b = p1.get(1);
        int count = 0;

        for (List<Integer> p2 : inp1) {
            int c = p2.get(0), d = p2.get(1);

            if (c >= a && d >= b)
                count++;
        }

        list.add(count);
    }

    return list;
}
```

This program works for small inputs as time complexity is O(N^2), but my input list can be very large so the program fails with time-out errors. How to improve this code? I am looking for a condition to break the inner loop or some other better approach to solve this task.

**Constraints:**

```
Size of the input list is 1 to 10^5.

x coordinate of inp1 is 1 to 10^9
y coordinate of inp1 is 1 to 100

x coordinate of inp2 is 0 to 10^9
y coordinate of inp2 is 0 to 100
```

**Update:**

I have tried the approach mentioned by @user1984, but still, the code fails when the input range is very high with time-out errors. How can I improve this solution further?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(process(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1, 2), Arrays.asList(2, 3), Arrays.asList(1, 5)),
            Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1, 1), Arrays.asList(1, 4))));
}

public static List<Integer> process(List<List<Integer>> inp1, List<List<Integer>> inp2) {
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for (List<Integer> list : inp1) {
        int k = list.get(0);
        List<Integer> v = map.getOrDefault(k, new ArrayList<>());
        map.put(k, v);
        v.add(list.get(1));
    }
    List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
    for (int key : keys) {
        List<Integer> list = map.get(key);
        Collections.sort(list);
    }

    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<Integer> list : inp2) {
        int x = list.get(0);
        int y = list.get(1);
        // Get the starting index for x coordinate
        int k = startsFrom(keys, x);
        if (k == -1) {
            result.add(0);
        } else {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = k; i < keys.size(); i++) {
                List<Integer> values = map.get(keys.get(i));
                // Get the starting index for y coordinate
                int k1 = startsFrom(values, y);
                if (k1 != -1) {
                    count += values.size() - k1;
                }
            }
            result.add(count);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
// Get the index where target can be found in list
private static int startsFrom(List<Integer> list, int target) {
    int s = 0, e = list.size() - 1;
    int k = -1;
    while (s <= e) {
        int m = (s + e) / 2;
        if (list.get(m) < target) {
            s = m + 1;
        } else {
            k = m;
            e = m - 1;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

**update:**
Additional Test case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(process(Arrays.asList(a(6, 15), a(6, 12), a(9, 13), a(9, 16), a(10, 15), a(14, 15), 
                a(13, 14), a(15, 20), a(11, 16), a(10, 18), a(13, 12), a(10, 20),
                a(6, 16), a(5, 11), a(7, 10), a(13, 11), a(9, 12), a(14, 17), 
                a(9, 17), a(8, 16), a(11, 19), a(9, 11), a(10, 12), a(13, 17),
                a(8, 14), a(14, 12), a(12, 14), a(15, 12), a(5, 15), a(7, 18),
                a(13, 15), a(5, 16), a(7, 16), a(7, 11), a(14, 18), a(6, 18),
                a(12, 12), a(5, 14), a(8, 12), a(6, 17), a(6, 19), a(15, 18),
                a(13, 18), a(5, 12), a(9, 15), a(6, 20), a(14, 10), a(9, 18),
                a(12, 15), a(6, 11)), 
                
                Arrays.asList(a(4, 16), a(2, 6), a(7, 4), a(15, 9), a(15, 15), a(6, 13),
                        a(14, 10), a(8, 9), a(7, 1), a(11, 6), a(2, 6), a(11, 1), a(11, 0),
                        a(4, 4), a(3, 20), a(9,6), a(13,13), a(1,3), a(2,7),
                        a(4,10), a(14,18), a(2,9), a(0,3), a(12,6), a(14,10), a(9,9),
                        a(15,12), a(3,14), a(15,6), a(7,2), a(14,15), a(9,7),
                        a(1,12), a(13,15), a(0,9), a(15,20), a(6,6), a(12,0), a(5,13),
                        a(7,17), a(15,15), a(5,10), a(14,14), a(1,3), a(13, 8), a(9,19), a(12,9), a(15,4), a(0,5), a(8,16))));
        
    }
 
   private static List<Integer> a(int i, int j) {
        return Arrays.asList(i, j);
    }
```

Expected output for this is :

```
[22, 50, 37, 3, 2, 31, 8, 33, 37, 19, 50, 19, 19, 50, 3, 30, 9, 50, 50, 50, 3, 50, 50, 17, 8, 30, 3, 33, 3, 37, 5, 30, 43, 8, 50, 1, 45, 17, 34, 12, 2, 50, 5, 50, 14, 3, 17, 3, 50, 14]
```

Based on soltion provided by `Mohaned El-haddad` I tried below code, but this code is giving wrong output as `[3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 8, 3, 8, 5, 5, 9, 8, 14, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 30, 30, 30, 3, 33, 14, 37, 37, 37, 12, 31, 45, 34, 50, 22, 50, 50, 3, 33, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 43, 50, 50, 50, 50]` for my `Additional Test case`.

```
public static List<Integer> process(List<List<Integer>> rectangles, List<List<Integer>> points) {
    int[] freq_arr = new int[101];

    rectangles.sort((r1, r2) -> r2.get(0) - r1.get(0));

    points.sort((p1, p2) -> p2.get(0) - p1.get(0));

    int idx = 0;

    int N = rectangles.size();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<Integer> point : points) {
        while (idx < N && rectangles.get(idx).get(0) >= point.get(0)) {
            add(freq_arr, rectangles.get(idx).get(1));
            idx++;
        }
        list.add(calc(freq_arr, point.get(1)));
    }
    return list;
}

private static int calc(int[] freq_arr, int b) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = b; i < freq_arr.length; i++) {
        count += freq_arr[i];
    }
    return count;
}

private static void add(int[] freq_arr, int y) {
    freq_arr[y]++;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *`time out errors`*?

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I think we can use line sweep.

Comment: @PM77-1, my code time complexity is O(N^2) as my input range is very large, it is taking very large time, which is not effiecient. I am looking for a point where I can break the inner loop or some other approach to reduce the time complexity.

Comment: @Someone, can you explain what is line sweep.

Comment: @learner, here is a [brief intro](https://www.thealgorists.com/Algo/SweepLine).

Comment: I see there are requests to close my post, is there something wrong with my question?

Comment: _Size of the input list is 1 to 10^5_ there are two input lists. Does it apply to both ?

Comment: @c0der, yes both for them have same range.

Comment: A small improvement can be gained by using an array to represent each pair :  `List<Integer[]>`

Comment: @c0der, can you explain more, even list.get(i) is same as array[i] in terms of time complexity right?

Comment: See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16565376/3992939

Comment: @c0der, it says just 25% faster, but that is not much improvement.

Comment: [2-d tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) to the rescue?

Comment: The output is correct you just didn't save the initial order of points before the sorting so you are putting the answer in the wrong order so instead of this line list.add(calc(freq_arr, point.get(1))  use   list[point.get(2)] = calc(freq_arr, point.get(1));      where point.get(2) is the index of the point in the input

Answer (score 2):

Your curreent solution has TC `O(n * m)` where `n` and `m` are the length of the rectangle array and points array.

Here's a possible improvement in terms of TC:

1. Create a sorted map with keys being the `x` coordinates of the rectangles and the values an array of the `y` coordinates that have those `x`.
2. Make sure the map is sorted increasing on the keys.
3. Iterate over the points. For each point do the following:

- Find the minimum key (x coordinate) that covers the x coordinate of that point. This operation is logarithmic since the map is sorted. You can be sure that all the keys after this key also cover the point.
- Check the values of all keys greater than or equal to the found key. These are the y values. If they satisfy the condition, add them to your result.

To improve your algorithm: Also sort the values of the map. This way, finding the minimum satisfying y coordinate also takes logarithmic time and you don't need to check the rest. You can just subtract that index from the value array length.

Comment: Isn't this the [line sweep algo](https://www.thealgorists.com/Algo/SweepLine)?

Comment: What I proposed isn't the line sweep algo. I'm thinking that if we were dealing with one dimension, we could use the line sweep algo. But since we need to check also the y coordinates it wouldn't work. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: hey @Someone I skimmed the article you posted. I had a somewhat different view of the line sweep algorithm. You are correct. What I'm proposing has some fundamental similarities with the line sweep algo.

Comment: `Find the minimum key (x coordinate) that covers the x coordinate of that point. This operation is logarithmic since the map is sorted. You can be sure that all the keys after this key also cover the point.` Once I get the minimum key, how can I get the index of that key in map to iterate for other remaining keys. Because in Java, map has no indexO method. Same applies to map values also.

Comment: If that's the case, then don't use a map at all. Create a simple array of instances of a class that has an int for x and another array for the ys that have that x in a rectangle. Then sort the array with a custom comparator based on the x values of the class instances. Now, you can binary search for the minimum index with an x that covers your point and can index the rest too. You could also use an array of array instead of array of class. In this approach, you can say that the first element of the inner arrays is the x coord and the rest the y coords that have such an x. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @user1984, if arrays of x is sorted, then the order of elements in array y will be out of sync right as the x elements order changed now. How to maintain that

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain a simple solution by using only sorting, frequency array and 2 pointers.

- For a point (a,b) to lies inside a rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2) 4 conditions must be met.

  1. a >= x1
  2. a <= x2
  3. b >= y1
  4. b <= y2

since in this problem x1=0 and y1=0 and a>=0
then condition 1 and 3 are always satisfied.
Now we need to check for each query point how many rectangles satisfy the two remaining conditon.
lets rename x2 to x and y2 to y since the other value are always zero.

1) x >= a 
2) y >= b


Take a look at the constraints you will find that MAX_Y = 100 we will use this to check if the second condition is met.
how can we solve this easly ?
lets create an freq_arr[MAX_Y+1];
when we want to add a new rectangle(x,y) to our freq_arr we will do

```
void add(freq_arr,y){
    freq_arr[y]++;
}
```

when have a point(a,b)
when we want to query how many rectangle have their y >= b we can do this:

```
void calc(freq_arr,b){
    int count =0;
    for(int i = b;i<=MAX_Y;i++)count+=freq_arr[i];
    return count;
}
```

This way we can check if the condition(2) is satisfied in O(MAX_Y).

let's do a little trick that will help us make sure the condition(1) is always satisfied

1. sort all rectangles in decreasing order of x.
2. sort all point in decreasing order of x.
3. let's create a pointer to rectangles array and called it rectangle_idx_to_be_added and initalize it with zero.
4. let's iterate over points array to answer each point separately.

   ```
   for(auto point : points){
      // add all rectangles that have x>=a to freq_arr
      while(rectangle_idx_to_be_added <N &&
      rectangles[rectangle_idx_to_be_added].x >= point.a){
          add(freq_arr,rectangles[rectangle_idx_to_be_added].y);
          rectangle_idx_to_be_added++;
      }
      // at this point all the points in the the freq_arr have x>=a 
      // and all we need to check is how many y >= b
      // which we can do easily using the freq_arr
      ans[point.query_idx] = calc(freq_arr,point.b);
   }
   ```

```
Time complexity O(NlogN + N*MAX_Y)
```

NlogN for sorting and N*MAX_Y for answering the queries

Comment: I tired your approach and updated my post again. It is giving wrong output for my updated test case which I posted recenyly. This solution is giving output as `[3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 8, 3, 8, 5, 5, 9, 8, 14, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 30, 30, 30, 3, 33, 14, 37, 37, 37, 12, 31, 45, 34, 50, 22, 50, 50, 3, 33, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 43, 50, 50, 50, 50]` But actual output should be `[22, 50, 37, 3, 2, 31, 8, 33, 37, 19, 50, 19, 19, 50, 3, 30, 9, 50, 50, 50, 3, 50, 50, 17, 8, 30, 3, 33, 3, 37, 5, 30, 43, 8, 50, 1, 45, 17, 34, 12, 2, 50, 5, 50, 14, 3, 17, 3, 50, 14]` how to fix this issue.

Comment: The output is correct you just didn't save the initial order of points before the sorting so you are putting the answer in the wrong order so instead of this line
<br/> list.add(calc(freq_arr, point.get(1)) <br/> use list[point.get(2)] = calc(freq_arr, point.get(1)); <br/> where point.get(2) is the index of the point in the input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simplify the problem by using special data structures, e.g. `TreeSet`.

Another obvious way is that you have to create a data structure, to efficiently retrieve required points.

I offer to use `TreeSet` to efficiently retrieve all points within a given range and then use two `HashMap` to efficiently receive points by their coordinates.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> inp1 = List.of(List.of(1, 2), List.of(2, 3), List.of(1, 5));
        List<List<Integer>> points = List.of(List.of(1, 1), List.of(1, 4));
        List<Integer> counts = process(inp1, points);
        System.out.println(counts); // [3, 1]
    }

    private static final class Point {

        private final int x;
        private final int y;
        private int count;

        public Point(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

    }

    public static List<Integer> process(List<List<Integer>> inp1, List<List<Integer>> inp2) {
        return processPoints(
                inp1.stream()
                    .map(i -> new Point(i.get(0), i.get(1)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()),
                inp2.stream()
                    .map(i -> new Point(i.get(0), i.get(1)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

    private static List<Integer> processPoints(List<Point> rectangles, List<Point> points) {
        NavigableSet<Integer> uniqueSortedX = getSortedByX(points);
        NavigableSet<Integer> uniqueSortedY = getSortedByY(points);
        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Point>> map = getMap(points);

        for (Point rectangle : rectangles) {
            for (int x : uniqueSortedX.subSet(0, true, rectangle.x, true)) {
                if (!map.containsKey(x))
                    continue;

                Set<Integer> ys = new HashSet<>(uniqueSortedY.subSet(0, true, rectangle.y, true));
                ys.retainAll(map.get(x).keySet());

                for (int y : ys)
                    if (map.get(x).containsKey(y))
                        map.get(x).get(y).count++;
            }
        }

        return points.stream()
                     .map(point -> point.count)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static NavigableSet<Integer> getSortedByX(List<Point> points) {
        NavigableSet<Integer> unique = new TreeSet<>();

        points.stream()
              .map(point -> point.x)
              .forEach(unique::add);

        return unique;
    }

    private static NavigableSet<Integer> getSortedByY(List<Point> points) {
        NavigableSet<Integer> unique = new TreeSet<>();

        points.stream()
              .map(point -> point.y)
              .forEach(unique::add);

        return unique;
    }

    private static Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Point>> getMap(List<Point> points) {
        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Point>> map = new HashMap<>();
        points.forEach(point ->
                map.computeIfAbsent(point.x, x -> new HashMap<>()).put(point.y, point));
        return map;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I added an additional test case to my post, when I ran the code using that test case your solution is giving me result as `[22, 0, 37, 3, 0, 31, 0, 33, 37, 19, 50, 19, 19, 50, 3, 30, 9, 0, 50, 50, 3, 50, 50, 17, 8, 30, 3, 33, 3, 37, 5, 30, 43, 8, 50, 1, 45, 17, 34, 12, 2, 50, 5, 50, 14, 3, 17, 3, 50, 14]` But the expected result is `[22, 50, 37, 3, 2, 31, 8, 33, 37, 19, 50, 19, 19, 50, 3, 30, 9, 50, 50, 50, 3, 50, 50, 17, 8, 30, 3, 33, 3, 37, 5, 30, 43, 8, 50, 1, 45, 17, 34, 12, 2, 50, 5, 50, 14, 3, 17, 3, 50, 14]`. Can you please check that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not specialist in Java, that's why I can't help you with code, but I will try to explain an algorithm to solve the issue.

Due to amount of data you need to reduce the number of comparisons. This can be achieved by special hierarchical structure of nested rectangles.

From the example on the top of your issue with rectangles [[1,2], [2,3], [1,5]] you will have on the top level of such structure two branches:

[2,3] and [1,5]

on the second layer [2,3] will have a child [1,2]

[1,5] will not have any children

As a result, when you will check every point, you will start from the top and will work with only branches that include the point.

On the big amount of data you will have much better performance by discarding unnecessary branches.

To improve performance further, you will need to store in every node the depths of child branches.